# How to ignore @class type during deserialize by jackson

Tags: jackson, objectmapper

I have two project A and B,
project A serialized a dto, and cached into redis, String like :

```
{"@class":"com.mike.xxxx.DtoDemo","id":88888,"name":"xxxxx"}
```

this cache was used by A and B too.
so, project A has no question.

But project B has question:
InvalidTypeIdException:Could not resolve type id 'com.mike.xxxx.DtoDemo' as a subtype of xxx

then I disable FAIL_ON_INVALID_SUBTYPE

```
ObjectMapper mapper = Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json()
    .featuresToDisable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_INVALID_SUBTYPE)
...

mapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY);
```

but, in project B, always get null result.
How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

in project A, keep this code, don't need change,
and project B, comment this code:

```
// mapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY);
```

and it works now.

Comment: return type is "java.util.LinkedHashMap", so you need
 ```
mapper.readValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(ret), methodReturnType)
```